# How to Append existing integer in DB ACCESS with new integer from java

Tags: java, sql, database, ms-access

for example 
i have a table in access name : `Sale`
in sale table have 2 column: `productID,sale_Quantity`

existing data in ACESS:

```
productID = G001 | sale_Quantity =2
```

in java user input G001 and sale_quantity 3.. so i want to update the data in `ACCESS` so that

```
`sale_Quantity= 2+3..` total is 5..
```

how the sql statement?
tq..

this is my 2 sql statement that i have try in java..

`st.executeUpdate ("UPDATE Product(productID,sale_quantity) SET sale_quantity=sale_quantity+quantity[i] WHERE productID('"+productID[i]+"');"); // UPDATE ROWS IN PRODUCTS`

```
st.executeUpdate("UPDATE SALE SET sale_quantity=sale_quantity+quantity[i] WHERE productID='productID[i]'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you correct the SQL String as below. In your code you need to append the values as below.

```
String sql = "UPDATE SALE SET "
               + " sale_quantity = (sale_quantity + " + quantity[i] + ") " 
               + " WHERE productID = " + productID[i];

st.executeUpdate(sql).
```

Comment: this error when i try..
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)